# Critique my proof of: Suppose $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are sets. Prove that $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \subseteq (A \cup C) \times (B \cup D)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Critique my proof on correctness, structure, etc.

*Proof.* Let $p = (x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup (C \times D)$. Thus, $(x, y) \in (A \times B)$ or $(x, y) \in (C \times D)$.

**Case #1**

Suppose $(x, y) \in (A \times B)$. By definition of cartesian product, $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. It follows that $x \in (A \cup C)$ and $y \in (B \cup D)$ by definition of union.

**Case #2**

Suppose $(x, y) \in (C \times D)$. By definition of cartesian product, $x \in C$ and $y \in D$. It follows that $x \in A \cup C$ and $y \in C \cup D$ by definition of union.

$\therefore$ Because $(x, y)$ is an arbitrary element of $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D)$, $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \subseteq (A \cup C) \times (B \cup D)$.

Comment: Yes, I see it well.

Comment: It looks fine to me! Maybe as a side quest try to prove the converse $\subseteq$ or find a counterexample ... 
edit: one small thing I've noticed: maybe don't say let $p = (x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup(C \times D)$ but say let $p \in (A \times B) \cup (C \times D)$ and only say that $p$ is a cartesian product once you're in the two cases. So if $p \in (A \times B) \cup(C \times D)$ then $p \in A \times B$ or $p \in C \times D.$ In the first case, we can find $x \in A$ and $y\in B$ such that $p = (x,y)$ etc.

Comment: of course the converse is $\supseteq$, and $p$ is not a cartesian product, it's in a cartesian product. I'm getting tired

Comment: I think knowing when to use proof by cases is the key, and you know it very well.

Comment: I would add one more step at the end of each case:  after saying $x \in A \cup C$ and $y \in B \cup D$, I would say "and therefore $(x, y) \in (A \cup C) \times (B \cup D)$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof is very tight and if I was grading it I'd give it full credit.

If you want to be more concise you could say that since the union operator is commutative, that proving only case one is necessary since case two is the same argument just relabeling the sets.

Something along the lines of

> Without loss of generality, assume that $(x,y)\in A\times B$. This means that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ which, by definition of the union means that $x\in A\cup C $ and $y\in B\cup D \implies (x,y)\in(A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$. The same argument can be made if $(x,y)\in C\times D$.

> $\therefore$ since all $p\in (A\times B)\cup(C\times D)\implies p\in (A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$ we can say $(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)\subseteq  (A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$. Q.E.D.

However, perhaps I should not be encouraging people to be lazy in proofs like me